# How to use require function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

```
const path = require("path");
console.log('The file name is ${path.basename(__filename)}');
```

I am not getting the file name after using this. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
console.log('The file name is ${path.basename(__filename)}');
```

is using regular quote marks.  If you want to use the template features of Javascript like `${path.basename(__filename)}`, then you have to use the backtick, not a regular quote to delineate your string:

```
console.log(`The file name is ${path.basename(__filename)}`);
```

Note the different backtick quote marks at beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just started learning this.